# Array of JLabel vs. Graphics2D Painting

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, jlabel

I have to create a connect 5 game with a GUI for my CS course final project. I worked with Graphics2D for the last project - a Maze - and working with Graphics2D was a nightmare. At most, the connect5 board will be 20x20, which would be an Area of 400. I was wondering what the performance implications of creating an Array of 400 JLabels to handle the GUI, since it will be easy to determine a mouse click within boundaries, get the array induces, and changing the color of space along with other similar operations whereas the same operations would be much more difficult with Graphics2D. So, my overall question is: would creating an array of that many JLabels be undesirable? If so, what other alternatives might I have? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens. Creating an array of 400 labels is not a big issue. ` it will be easy to determine a mouse click within boundaries` I agree since you can add the same MouseListener to each label.

Answer (score 1):

I think the JLabel approach would be undesirable, I think one component with custom painting would be more desirable, because it seems a bit easier.

If you have your classes in that abstract format not tied to the UI or anything (so playable even on the command line where you could output in a text a representation of the board), then it should be simple to loop through the spaces representing the board and make the small set of drawing calls to draw each slot (empty or not).

Seems better to if you wanted to introduce animations like pieces falling down and then bumping up for a while when they hit the piece below it.

Comment: So when you say "set of drawing calls," what exactly do you mean by drawing call? Is drawing some method? The only type of painting I know how to do is by over-riding PaintComponent and I feel like that may be my major issue with UI here. Maybe there is something more versatile?

Comment: By drawing calls I mean the drawing methods that come with a Graphics2D object, preferably in an overridden paintComponent. If you know how to do that, you should be in good shape. Create a custom component that extends JComponent, create a constructor that takes Connect5Board object or whatever you have, in the paintComponent method loop through the representation of the Connect5 board and draw the pieces or empty slots one by one. Use methods like getWidth and getHeight to know how much space you have to draw, so you can constrain how large you'll draw a slot.

Comment: You could even add a MouseListener to the component and when you click in a specific column you can modify the Connect5Board object to place a piece in that column, switch whose turn it is, and whatever else you need to do.